# Oracle 10g: How to make a matrix report repeat on reaching the end of page

Tags: oracle10g, oraclereports

I have an oracle report (10g) which spans multiple pages due to the number of items in the repeating frame.
Is there a way to get the repeating frame to "wrap" when it reaches the end of the page (basically start a new line of values beneath the original values)?

I tried setting the print direction property to across/down, but it gave me an "REP-1232: Matrix '' has an invalid source frame." error.

Any ideas on how I could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

In the property inspector for your repeating frame Advanced Layout section: 
Print Object On: First Page
Base Printing on: Enclosing Object
Keep With Anchoring Object: Yes